# Disable Hyperlink in DatagridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF Data grid which is bound to a list of custom class objects using the ItemsSource Property. 
Grid has a DataGridHyperlinkColum that is bind to a property/field in custom class.
I want this hyperlink to be disabled when another property in the custom class has a specific value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` + template with `Hyperlink` (e.g. using [TemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I couldn't explain it better than tutorials: [click](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/) + [click](https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`.

The following sample markup will disable the `Hyperlink` when `YourOtherProperty` returns "x":

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="ColA" Binding="{Binding YourLinkProperty}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourOtherProperty}" Value="x">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

It should give you the idea.

Comment: I think he needs `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=DataContext.YourOtherProperty}` in order to access `YourOtherProperty`, but not entirely sure right now

Comment: @grek40: He does not provided that "YourOtherProperty" is a property of the type T in the IEnumerable<T> ItemsSource collection.

Comment: actually he does... *"Grid has a DataGridHyperlinkColum that is bind to a property/field in custom class"* and *"another property in the custom class"*. Might not be entirely clear, but the default assumption should be that "custom class" refers to the collection items.

Comment: @grek40: Read the question again: "I have a WPF Data grid which is bound to a list of custom class objects using the ItemsSource Property...". The custom class is the the type T here I guess.

Comment: I think i mixed it up with problems I had with the Extended WPF `DataGridControl` columns, where the column property will become the `DataContext` for most inner bindings, sorry.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Marked as answer.

Comment: One more question, How can I disable the hyperlink if I have a condition like if value is "value 1" or value is "value 2" or value contains "some string" ?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: I am trying to make it not visible based on some condition instead of making it disabled. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I needed similar functionality of disabling a link in WPF DataGrid cell, but in my cell there is EventSetter so I needed some modification of the solution proposed by @mm8

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Converter={x:Static util:GetMemberName.Instance}}" Header="Member Name">
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="{Binding HasPermission}">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style>
                <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Member_Hyperlink_Click" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```